# Login screen: Mate is default but not selected

Tags: login, lightdm, mate

I changed the variable `user-session=ubuntu` to `user-session=mate` in the file `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`. On the login screen, although Mate is default, it is not selected by default.

How to configure Mate to be marked as selected on this screen?
OS: Ubuntu 16.04

[image: login screen]

Comment: On my system, it keeps the last choice that you logged in under.

Comment: I concur with @OrganicMarble. Does the same happen if you create a new (temporary) user? What is its pre-set desktop session type?

Comment: I need to know which user profile file this information is saved. I need to leave this set to use mate